# Restful Web Service runs in Shell but not Eclipse indigo,it gives class not found exception

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jersey-1.0

I'm using Eclipse INDIGO, Apache-tomcat-7.0.42 and jersay libraries. I export my project as war into \apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps folder and run server from cmd, It does not throw any exception. But when I tried to run my project as run on server it gives below exception

```
Aug 10, 2013 11:29:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Aug 10, 2013 11:29:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Jersey-Servlet as unavailable
Aug 10, 2013 11:29:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
: Servlet /sc threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
at            .apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I found some issues in jersey libraries when I searched my error in web.. but I couldn't found any solution. i add this libraries. But it gives same error.

jersey-servlet-1.13-b01.jar

jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar

jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar

Please help me....

Comment: wjy you have both these jars jersey-servlet-1.13-b01.jar, jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar ?

Comment: I didn't add both at once.. I add one by one and run. But it gives same exception.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add jersey-core.jar

see [mykyong.com same issue resolution](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletcontainer/)